# Co-spinors and contra-spinors

Tags: tensor-calculus, group-theory, definition, group-representations, spinors

As i was reading my teacher's notes on $SU(2)$ and $SO(3)$, i have had this question. Why do co-spinors transform differently under a rotation than contra-spinors?

Comment: The terminology is rather uncommon. What do they mean?

Comment: He described co-spinors as $$u^{a'} =X^{a}_{\ {b}} u^b$$ and contra-spinors as the complex conjugate but with subscripts

Comment: This is odd and confusing, since it's the opposite of tensors!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [3D rotation group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group) $SO(3)$ has double-cover $SU(2)$, which is a subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$.

TL;DR: A spinor index of a 2-component spinor is raised and lowered with the 2D [Levi-Civita symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol), which can informally be viewed as a "symplectic [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor)" for the [symplectic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_group) $Sp(2,\mathbb{C})\cong SL(2,\mathbb{C})$.

In more detail, in case of the [Lie group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group) $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$,

- the [fundamental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_representation)/defining [representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation) $\rho={\rm id}:SL(2,\mathbb{C})\to SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ is the left-handed Weyl spinor representation;
- the [dual/contragredient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_representation)/transposed representation is $$g~~\mapsto~~ (\rho(g)^{-1})^T~=~\epsilon \rho(g)\epsilon^{-1},\qquad g~\in~SL(2,\mathbb{C}),$$ and hence an [equivalent representation](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=equivalent+representations) to $\rho$;
- the [complex conjugate representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_representation) $\bar{\rho}$ is the right-handed Weyl spinor representation. If we restrict $\bar{\rho}$ to $SU(2)$, it is equivalent to (the restriction of) $\rho$.

Comment: Thanks! So the distinction between co- and contra-spinors are not as important as that between co- and contra-vectors? Namely, you would need a metric to identify co- and contra-vectors. For co- and contra-spinors, are you saying that the "metric" is already there?

Comment: Yes, for the spinors discussed here.

Comment: I see, so for example, would this distinction become important for 4-component spinors?

Comment: Referring to the notation set up in my reply, the 4-component spinors come out of $⊕\bar{}$, where the metric $g$ splits into $ε⊗\bar{ε}$, with $ε$ being the metric for the $$ part and $\bar{ε}$ the metric for the $\bar{}$ part. By convention $$ is deemed the right-handed helicity part, $\bar{}$ the left-handed helicity part. The distinction involves parity. For fermions with positive rest mass, the Dirac equation entails an oscillation between the two parts.

Answer (score 0):

As alluded to in commentary, there is a metric for spinors. (**Edit**: which is underlies the distinction between covariant and contravariant.) Watch, as I do a little magic and pull one out of the hat ... and a lot more, besides that!

In a Lorentzian space-time, one can always choose a frame of the form $\left(h^0, h^1, h^2, h^3\right)$, such that the components of the dual metric with respect to it are given by:
$$g^{-1}\left(h^a, h^b\right) = h^{ab}, \hspace 1em \left(h^{ab}: a, b = 0, 1, 2, 3\right) = \text{diag}(+, -, -, -).$$
The line element of the metric $g$, with respect to this frame is:
$$g = h^0 h^0 - h^1 h^1 - h^2 h^2 - h^3 h^3.$$
I am, here, denoting tensor products by juxtaposition (e.g. $h^0 h^0$ for $h^0 ⊗ h^0$).

For clarity, the elements of the frame are co-vectors, i.e. $h^a = h^a_μ dx^μ$. Thus, $g_{μν} = h^a_μ h^b_ν h_{ab}$, where $h_{ab} = h^{ab}$ (the frame components of the metric, as a matrix, is equal to its own inverse).

Now ... we'll define
$$
L = \frac{h^0 + h^3}{\sqrt{2}}, \hspace 1em M = \frac{h^1 - i h^2}{\sqrt{2}}, \hspace 1em \bar{M} = \frac{h^1 + ih^2}{\sqrt{2}}, \hspace 1em N = \frac{h^0 - h^3}{\sqrt{2}}.
$$
This is a skew-frame, not orthonormal, nor even orthogonal. Substituting, we find:
$$
LN = \frac{h^0 h^0 - h^0 h^3 + h^3 h^0 - h^3 h^3}{2}, \\
M\bar{M} = \frac{h^1 h^1 + i h^1 h^2 - i h^2 h^1 + h^2 h^2}{2}, \\
\bar{M}M = \frac{h^1 h^1 - i h^1 h^2 + i h^2 h^1 + h^2 h^2}{2}, \\
NL = \frac{h^0 h^0 + h^0 h^3 - h^3 h^0 - h^3 h^3}{2}.
$$
Thus:
$$LN - M\bar{M} - \bar{M}M + NL = h^0 h^0 - h^1 h^1 - h^2 h^2 - h^3 h^3 = g.$$

Now ... we will adopt the following axiom, that the frame splits:
$$L = ο\bar{ο}, \hspace 1em M = ο\bar{ι}, \hspace 1em \bar{M} = ι\bar{ο}, \hspace 1em N = ι\bar{ι}.$$
This involves a split of $: (L, M, \bar{M}, N)$ into $: (ο, ι)$ and $\bar{}: (\bar{ο}, \bar{ι})$. We will also postulate that the products of the $$ frame commute with those of the $\bar{}$ frame:
$$
ο\bar{ο} = \bar{ο}ο, \hspace 1em ο\bar{ι} = \bar{ι}ο, \hspace 1em ι\bar{ο} = \bar{ο}ι, \hspace 1em ι\bar{ι} = \bar{ι}ι.
$$

Then, it follows that
$$\begin{align}
LN - M\bar{M} - \bar{M}M + NL
&= ο\bar{ο}ι\bar{ι} - ο\bar{ι}ι\bar{ο} - ι\bar{ο}ο\bar{ι} + ι\bar{ι}ο\bar{ο} \\
&= οι\bar{ο}\bar{ι} - οι\bar{ι}\bar{ο} - ιο\bar{ο}\bar{ι} + ιο\bar{ι}\bar{ο} \\
&= \left(οι - ιο\right)\left(\bar{ο}\bar{ι} - \bar{ι}\bar{ο}\right).
\end{align}$$

Thus,
$$g = ε\bar{ε},$$
where
$$ε ≡ ο∧ι ≡ οι - ιο, \hspace 1em \bar{ε} ≡ \bar{ο}∧\bar{ι} ≡ \bar{ο}\bar{ι} - \bar{ι}\bar{ο}.$$
The metric $g$ over $$ splits into a metric $ε$ over $$ and a metric $\bar{ε}$ over $\bar{}$.

But, wait ... there's more!

$L$, $M$, $\bar{M}$ and $N$ are not just co-vectors, but one-forms. What about two-forms? Set
$$
Z^+ ≡ οο, \hspace 1em Z^0 ≡ \frac{οι + ιο}{\sqrt{2}}, \hspace 1em Z^- ≡ ιι, \\
\bar{Z^+} ≡ \bar{ο}\bar{ο}, \hspace 1em \bar{Z^0} ≡ \frac{\bar{ο}\bar{ι} + \bar{ι}\bar{ο}}{\sqrt{2}}, \hspace 1em \bar{Z^-} ≡ \bar{ι}\bar{ι}.
$$
Then
$$
L∧M = LM - ML = ο\bar{ο}ο\bar{ι} - ο\bar{ι}ο\bar{ο} = οο\bar{ο}\bar{ι} - οο\bar{ι}\bar{ο} = οο\left(\bar{ο}\bar{ι} - \bar{ι}\bar{ο}\right) = Z^+ \bar{ε}.
$$
Similarly,
$$L∧\bar{M} = ε \bar{Z^+}.$$
For the other frame 2-forms, one gets:
$$M∧N = ε \bar{Z^-}, \hspace 1em \bar{M}∧N = Z^- \bar{ε},$$
and
$$
\frac{L∧N + M∧\bar{M}}{\sqrt{2}} = ε \bar{Z^0}, \hspace 1em
\frac{L∧N + \bar{M}∧M}{\sqrt{2}} = Z^0 \bar{ε}.
$$

Let's not forget the symmetric combinations - using the notation $a∨b = ab + ba$:
$$
LL = Z^+ \bar{Z^+}, \hspace 1em \frac{L∨M}{\sqrt{2}} = Z^+ \bar{Z^0}, \hspace 1em MM = Z^+ \bar{Z^-}, \\
\frac{L∨\bar{M}}{\sqrt{2}} = Z^0 \bar{Z^+}, \hspace 1em \frac{L∨N + M∨\bar{M}}{2} = Z^0 \bar{Z^0}, \hspace 1em \frac{M∨N}{\sqrt{2}} = Z^0 \bar{Z^-}, \\
\bar{M}\bar{M} = Z^- \bar{Z^-}, \hspace 1em \frac{\bar{M}∨N}{\sqrt{2}} = Z^- \bar{Z^0}, \hspace 1em NN = Z^- \bar{Z^-}.
$$
That realizes the following decompositions:
$$
∧ = \left(⊗\bar{}\right) ⊕ \left(⊗\bar{}\right), \hspace 1em
∨ = \left(⊗\bar{}\right) ⊕ \left(⊗\bar{}\right), \hspace 1em
⊗ = \left( ⊕ \right)⊗\left(\bar{} ⊕ \bar{}\right),
$$
with the frame bases:
$$
:(ε), \hspace 1em :\left(Z^+, Z^0, Z^-\right), \\
\bar{}:(\bar{ε}), \hspace 1em \bar{}:\left(\bar{Z^+}, \bar{Z^0}, \bar{Z^-}\right).
$$

That's the **full** decomposition that the decomposition of the metric is part of.